QGIS labeling based on an existing field
I have a point layer with several features in it that I generated starting from a line layer. The point layer inherited the field 'length' from the line layer. I would like to create a new field in which all the features with same value in the ' length' field will have the same id (example:1,2,3,...). Can I do this in the field calculator?

May I suggest you to change the title of your question as your problem doesn't seem to be labelling but rather calculating a commun "ID" for feature of same "lenght"

If there aren't too many different values in the length field you could run a selection for one, use the calculator to populate the new field with your id, then repeat for the other values.  If you have a lot of different values you could create a table with those values and the id you want for each, add it to your project and run a join using the length field and either use a calculator to copy the id field from that table to your new field, or export to a new layer.

John's suggestion is exactly the route I would take too. Give these approaches a shot

Thank you very much!

If you know what are you unique values for the field 'length', you can use the fhe function case from the field calculator.
They syntax is like this:
CASE
WHEN condition THEN result
[ …n ]
[ ELSE result ]
END

In your case, first you will need to create a new field called 'id', and then, by using the field calculator you can build the following expression:
CASE
WHEN "length"=<one of your values> THEN <id value>
[ repeat as many time as different length values you have]

END


THank you for your suggestion! I tried to do this but it gives me NULL at the end. Do you have any other suggestion?

I get the 'syntax error, unexpected LT' message and I don't know what LT means..

Maybe you can do the following:

Create a new field called 'id'.
In the attribute table, click on 'Select features using an expression'.
Then you can select all the features matching a desired length value by typing  (assuming you have a field called lenght for the length values):
"length" = 1000 (or the length value you need)
In the field calculator, click on 'Update existing field' and select your 'id' field. Be sure that the option 'Only selected features' is marked.
Now, type the id number that you want to assign.

Repeat the process for the rest of lenghts.

Thank you for your suggestion!
